# Should I store Type in database or should I store it in enum?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, uml

For example, I have a table name `Fruit` and each fruit belong to a `FruitType`. So should I store `FruitType` in data base then make a foreign key in `Fruit` or just store a reference id to `Enum` name `FruitType`

**Update:** 
The database is only used for one application. I need to display a table of `fruit` include their `fruit type` to user.I also use type as a filter in fruit table view. 
My current solution:
I will always have an `Enum` for `Type`. But
If the `Type` have more information than just `id` and `name` i.e `description` ... I will also store it in database so I can have a reference view to display all `Type` information. Other wise just `Enum`.

Comment: if the data is necessary in DB and should maybe useable anywhere in another applications, DB is the way to go. If not please provide more infos.

Comment: Can you make this a bit more concrete? What is the difference according to you between "FruitType" and "a reference id to Enum name FruitType" ? To me it seems like you're saying the same thing twice

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I mean id is referenced to `FruitType` record in database or id is referenced to `FruitType` in java Enum

Comment: @Patrick I just updated more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the database to save `FruitType`. I'll explain to two-ways to implement enum for the 'FruitType'. I assumed you're using `javax.persistance`.

```
enum FruitType {
 YELLOW,GREEN,RED;
}

class Fruit{
 private String name;
 @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) or @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private FruitType fruitType;
}
```

If you use EnumType.STRING then save string name of enum like (YELLOW, RED). For EnumType.ORDINAL save the order like 1,2 etc.

If you're planing to handle (adding,updating and deleting) lot of FruitTypes then use another table to keep data.

Comment: If you have few fruit type, then no need FruitType table.

Comment: So I should only choose one of them `Enum` or `Database` based on the need of handling (adding,updating and deleting)?

Comment: Yes, If you frequently change FruitType then go with table. If not you can use enum.

Answer (score 1):

If your types are static and you don't want to add them during app work time it's better to use enum. If there are really a lot of types or the types could be added/changed on fly it's better to store them in a separate DB table and set the relation.

Comment: Thank you, I will take this useful answer.